# Trimming ASP.NET Hyperlink Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, hyperlink

I have a question regarding applying a RTRIM on a ASP:Hyperlink statement.  The code I have is as follows:

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" class="iframe" ID="modelLink" 
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("AllAudits.aspx?model={0}&date={1}",
Trim(Eval("MODEL_NUMBER")), Trim(Eval("RECORD_DATE")))%>' 
Text='<%# Eval("MODEL_NUMBER") %>'> </asp:HyperLink>
```

Essentially, what I want it to do is pass MODEL_NUMBER and RECORD_DATE but I want to apply an RTRIM to the Eval statements.  I have searched literally everywhere and I am not sure what else to try.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, do that in a business layer (intermediate code) BEFORE you get to the page-side rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I got it working by using the following:

```
 NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("AllAudits.aspx?model={0}&date={1}",
Eval("MODEL_NUMBER").ToString().Trim(), Eval("RECORD_DATE").ToString().Trim())%>'
Text='<%# Eval("MODEL_NUMBER") %>'
```

Didn't think I'd be able to find it, but there it is!